# How to override method with method that has different type?

Tags: java

I have two classes

**GenericDaoWithObjectId.class**

```
public abstract class GenericDaoWithObjectId<T extends IEntity, Z extends Serializable> extends GenericDao<T> {
    public Map<Object, T> findByIdsAsMap(List<Object> ids, boolean addNonDeletedConstraint) throws DaoException {
        String query = addNonDeletedConstraint ? QUERY_FIND_NON_DELETED_BY_IDS : QUERY_FIND_BY_IDS;
        query = query.replaceAll("\\{type\\}", type);
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(query);
        q.setParameterList("ids", ids);
        List<T> entities = (List<T>) q.list();
        if (entities.size() != ids.size()) {
            throw new DaoException(DaoErrorCodes.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Map<Object, T> result = new HashMap<Object, T>(); // I would've done that in query (using SELECT new map(u.id, u), but hibernate has a bug...
        // (https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3345)
        for (T e : entities) {
            result.put(e.getId(), e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**GenericDao.class**

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T extends IEntity> {
    public Map<Long, T> findByIdsAsMap(List<Long> ids, boolean addNonDeletedConstraint) throws DaoException {
        String query = addNonDeletedConstraint ? QUERY_FIND_NON_DELETED_BY_IDS : QUERY_FIND_BY_IDS;
        query = query.replaceAll("\\{type\\}", type);
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(query);
        q.setParameterList("ids", ids);
        List<T> entities = (List<T>) q.list();
        if (entities.size() != ids.size()) {
            throw new DaoException(DaoErrorCodes.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Map<Long, T> result = new HashMap<Long, T>(); // I would've done that in query (using SELECT new map(u.id, u), but hibernate has a bug...
                                                      // (https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3345)
        for (T e : entities) {
            result.put((Long) e.getId(), e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And i want to override (or just create) method in GenericDao with method from GenericDaoWIthObjectId. The problem occurs because as i read JVM "think" that `List<Long>` and List`<Object>` and probably `Map<Long,T>` and `Map<Object,T>` is the same. How can I make it work?

Comment: "*I have **to** classes*" seems to be *I have **two** classes* :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can't overload  a method solely by type parameter; i.e., if two method signatures differ only by type parameters, they're considered the same method. This is because of Java's implementation of generics by *erasure* -- methods are stripped of their type parameters when they're compiled, so they would actually become the *same* method.

You can do this either by adding additional parameters to differentiate the two, or by changing the name of one of the methods; these are the only alternatives.

Comment: thank your for your answer. I was afraid this might be the only solution but if you are sure that theres nothing else i can do i will do that, thanks again.